# selenium - writing an xpath using the count function

Tags: selenium-webdriver, xpath

For a HTML page like this I'm writing two xpath statements to fetch the text from a td element. First xpath is to get the position of the th element that matches my requirement.

```
count(.//th[contains(., 'Header5')]/preceding-sibling::*)+1
```

Then I put the count value returned from the above to this xpath and get the text

```
.//tr[2]/td[**count**]
```

How can I merge these two xpaths in to single xpath and get the result. I tried something like this but it always selects the first td

```
.//tr[2]/td[count(.//th[contains(., 'Header5')]/preceding-sibling::*)+1]
(.//tr[2]/td)[count(.//th[contains(., 'Header5')]/preceding-sibling::*)+1]
```

Here is the html structure

```
<thead>
    <th> Header1 </th>
    <th> Header2 </th>
    <th> Header3 </th>
    <th> Header4 </th>
    <th> Header5 </th>
    <th> Header6 </th>
</thead>
<tbody>
    <tr>
    <tr>
        <td> Cell1 </td>
        <td> Cell2 </td>
        <td> Cell3 </td>
        <td> Cell4 </td>
        <td> Cell5 </td>
        <td> Cell6 </td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This one should do the trick:

```
.//tr[2]/td[count(//th[contains(., 'Header5')]/preceding-sibling::th) + 1]
```

Note that `/td[count(.//th)]` means *count of `th` nodes that are **descendants** of `td`* while `/td[count(//th)]` means *count of `th` wherever in DOM*, so be careful with the context node (the dot)

Comment: yeah, now i understood why my code didn't work. thanks for clarifying.